# Get rewrite result

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting

Quick simple question. How would I get the result of a rewrite in wordpress?

For example I have:

```
www.some.website.com/some/parameter
```

How would I get the end result that WP processes? Aka, the

```
www.some.website.com/index.php?paramter1=some&paramter2=parameter
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to see generally how requests are processed. After all the loading and init stuff happens, the `parse_request` action runs when the request is matched against the rewrite rules, and an object is passed containing all the registered query vars and the matched rule and query string.

```
function wpd_parse_request( $request ){
    echo $request->matched_query;
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_parse_request' );
```

After the `wp` action runs, that same object is stashed in the `wp` global.

```
global $wp;
echo $wp->matched_query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function get_query_var: [WordPress Codex Function Reference for get query var](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

```
$someVariable = get_query_var('paramter1');
```

Comment: But I wanted to get the entire string, not just one parameter and get_query_var demands that I pass a parameter to it.